# Touchable Opacity in FlatList doesn't respond to touch

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

**I am displaying the state array below using the FlatList provided.  However, the TouchableOpacity elements in Key exhibit no response whatsoever to a press. The issue persists even if I change the TO to a button or a pressable.  Does anyone have a solution for this issue because it has never happened before even when using very similar code.**

```
const [keyboard, setKeyboard] = useState([
        {char: 'a', background: 'white', border: 'black', text: 'black'},
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
        {char: 'z', background: 'white', border: 'black', text: 'black'},
    ]);

const Key = ({letter, background, border, textColor}) => {
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity style = {[styles.key, {backgroundColor: {background}}, {borderColor: {border}}]} onPress = {() => console.log({letter})}>
                <Text style = {[styles.letter, {color: {textColor}}]}>{letter}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };

<FlatList 
            contentContainerStyle = {styles.keyboard}
            data={keyboard}
            renderItem= {({item}) => <Key letter={item.char} background={item.background} border={item.border} textColor={item.text}/>}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.char}
            numColumns = {6}
        />
```

**Styles:**

```
keyboard:{
    width: '100%',
    height: '40%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    transform:[{translateY: 420}],
    flex: 1,
 },
 letter:{
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    position: 'absolute',

 },
 key:{
    height: 50,
    width: 60,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',

 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this code is that I had a Modal open.  TouchableOpacity components seem to not respond to touch when a Modal is open.  Instead use a conditionally rendered view.

```
{  {CONDITION HERE} ?(
       {WHAT WILL BE RENDERED IF CONDITION IS SATISFIED HERE}
):  {WHAT WILL BE RENDERED IF CONDITION IS NOT SATISFIED HERE; null or some other component}}
```

Answer (score 1):

the code is working fine ,
the issue with styling is your are passing its as object

```
 {background:{background}} instead this use {background:background}
```

here is the link of expo I tested
[see here its working with styling and also touchable](https://snack.expo.dev/@zeeshanshabbir/keyborad-stackoverflow)

hope its help you

Comment: This has solved the problem with the props however the issue with the TouchableOpacity not responding to touch persists.

Comment: I have attempted to add a touchable opacity and a button outside the FlatList as a test element and even those aren't working so the issue cannot be with the FlatList.

Comment: Its is responding on touch , you can check it by using console.log Or Alert on onpress event , correct me if i dont understand you question.

Comment: The buttons Z and X seem to not be working.  Is this an issue which occurs because of styling?