# Modal inside flatlist is bugging

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, flatlist

i'm using a Modal inside a flatlist using react native. But, when I click on the Icon that opens the modal, it starts to bug - the background becomes black and it starts to blink.
Any ideas on what is happening here? I'm using the modal from native-base and the iconbutton from react-native-paper. Thanks!

```
export function Prospecction() {
  const scrollY = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const initialRef = React.useRef(null);
  const finalRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
      <Animated.FlatList
        data={DATA}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: true }
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          padding: SPACING,
          paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 42,
        }}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          const inputRange = [
            -1,
            0,
            ITEM_SIZE * index,
            ITEM_SIZE * (index + 2),
          ];
          const opacityInputRange = [
            -1,
            0,
            ITEM_SIZE * index,
            ITEM_SIZE * (index + 1),
          ];

          const scale = scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange: [1, 1, 1, 0],
          });

          const opacity = scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: opacityInputRange,
            outputRange: [1, 1, 1, 0],
          });
          return (
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                elevation: 10,
                flexDirection: "row",
                padding: SPACING,
                marginBottom: SPACING,
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                borderRadius: 12,
              }}
            >
              <Modal
                isOpen={modalVisible}
                onClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}
                initialFocusRef={initialRef}
                finalFocusRef={finalRef}
              >
                <Modal.Content>
                  <Modal.CloseButton />
                  <Modal.Header>Adicionar comentário</Modal.Header>
                  <Modal.Body>
                    <FormControl>
                      <FormControl.Label>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                          Comentário
                        </Text>
                      </FormControl.Label>
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl mt="3">
                      <View style={{ padding: 1 }}>
                        <TextInput
                          style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            borderColor: "white",
                            borderRadius: 5,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            backgroundColor: "#E6E7ED",
                            textAlign: "left",
                          }}
                          placeholder="Digite seu comentário aqui"
                          autoFocus={true}
                          numberOfLines={10}
                          multiline
                        ></TextInput>
                      </View>
                    </FormControl>
                  </Modal.Body>
                  <Modal.Footer justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"}>
                    <Button.Group
                      justifyContent={"center"}
                      alignItems={"center"}
                    >
                      <Button
                        onPress={() => {
                          setModalVisible(false);
                        }}
                        justifyContent={"center"}
                        alignItems={"center"}
                        rounded={15}
                        height={55}
                        width="80%"
                        bgColor={"#250D8A"}
                        _pressed={{ bgColor: "#4530a7" }}
                      >
                        Adicionar
                      </Button>
                    </Button.Group>
                  </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal.Content>
              </Modal>

              <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: item.image }}
                    alt="Alternate Text"
                    size="xl"
                    style={{
                      width: AVATAR_SIZE,
                      height: AVATAR_SIZE,
                      borderRadius: AVATAR_SIZE,
                      marginRight: SPACING / 2,
                    }}
                  />

                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 22,
                        fontWeight: "700",
                        textAlign: "left",
                        marginTop: SPACING - 4,
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 13,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        fontWeight: "700",
                        textAlign: "left",
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.adate}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>

                <View
                  style={{ marginTop: SPACING - 5, flexDirection: "column" }}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 16,
                      opacity: 0.7,
                      textAlign: "left",
                      alignSelf: "flex-start",
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Interno:</Text>{" "}
                    {item.intern}{" "}
                  </Text>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 16,
                      opacity: 0.7,
                      textAlign: "left",
                      alignSelf: "flex-start",
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Externo:</Text>{" "}
                    {item.extern}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  marginTop: SPACING - 5,
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  marginLeft: 80,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: "700",
                    textAlign: "right",
                    color: "#7B61FF",
                    alignContent: "space-between",
                  }}
                ></Text>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  marginLeft: "5%",
                  marginTop: "5%",
                  right: 0,
                  flexWrap: "wrap",
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: "700",
                    textAlign: "right",
                    color: "#7B61FF",
                  }}
                >
                  {item.status}
                </Text>
              </View>

              <View
                style={{
                  marginTop: SPACING - 5,
                  flexGrow: 1,
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  marginTop: "auto",
                  flexWrap: "wrap-reverse",
                }}
              >
                <IconButton
                  icon="card-account-details-outline"
                  iconColor={MD3Colors.secondary30}
                  size={30}
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ClientInfo")}
                />
              </View>
            </Animated.View>
          );
        }}
      ></Animated.FlatList>
      <IconButton
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
        }}
        icon="plus-circle-outline"
        iconColor={MD3Colors.secondary30}
        size={30}
        onPress={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I suggest to put the modal outside the Flatlist and make the data should be shows in that modal stored in state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me when I was working on a hangman game.  The scaffold modals were preventing my FlatList of TouchableOpacities from being pressed when a modal was visible.  I suggest using a conditionally rendered View instead of a modal as that should fix your issue.

Refer to my question here: [Touchable Opacity in FlatList doesn't respond to touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73169103/touchable-opacity-in-flatlist-doesnt-respond-to-touch/73350609#73350609).